# Necessary and sufficient conditions $(L_1 \circ L_2)/L_2 = L_1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What conditions are necessary and sufficient for $(L_1 \circ L_2)/L_2 = L_1$ to be true, in which $L_1$ and $L_2$ are languages. I know one of the conditions is that $|L_2| > 0$. I know there is another but i can't seem to make a condition out of the sample cases I worked with.

Edit: Also what statement in predicate logic would I need to prove to show that the condition is necessary and sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

By definition $w\in(L_1\circ L_2)/L_2$ if and only if there is an $x\in L_2$ such that $wx\in L_1\circ L_2$; clearly this is the case if $w\in L_1$ and $L_2\ne\varnothing$, so $L_1\subseteq(L_1\circ L_2)/L_2$ whenever $L_2\ne\varnothing$. The problem is to find a necessary and sufficient condition for equality.

Clearly $L_1\subsetneqq(L_1\circ L_2)/L_2$ if and only if there is some $w\in\Sigma^*\setminus L_1$ such that $wx\in L_1\circ L_2$ for some $x\in L_2$; thus, we want some reasonably nice condition equivalent to saying that no such $w$ exists. Suppose that we have such a $w$; $wx\in L_1\circ L_2$, so there are $u\in L_1$ and $y\in L_2$ such that $uy=wx$. Note that in this case one of $x$ and $y$ must be a proper suffix of the other. (Why?)

- Show that such a $w$ exists if and only if there are $x,y\in\Sigma^*$ and $z\in L_2$ such that $xyz\in L_1\circ L_2$, $yz\in L_2$, and exactly one of $x$ and $xy$ is in $L_1$.
- Conclude that $L_1=(L_1\circ L_2)/L_2$ if and only if $L_2\ne\varnothing$, and whenever $xyz\in L_1\circ L_2$ with $yz,z\in L_2$, then either $\{x,xy\}\subseteq L_1$, or $\{x,xy\}\cap L_1=\varnothing$.

I don’t at the moment see any nicer way to state this condition.